# Pythonで管理者に昇格されるプログラムを起動する方法

Tags: python, windows

お世話になります。
Pythonのsubprocess.Popen等で、manifestで管理者権限起動が明示されたexeファイルを起動しようとしています。
しかし、実際にやってみると、

```
OSError: [WinError 740] 要求された操作には管理者特権が必要です。
```

という例外が起きて、起動できません。
何かよい方法はありますでしょうか。
環境は、Windows10 64ビット、Python3.7です。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 参考: 英語版SOでの類似質問 - [Run process as admin with subprocess.run in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47380378/2322778)

Comment: 起動した子プロセスの標準入出力を操作したいのでしょうか？ それとも新しいウィンドウが開かれるプログラムを起動できれば十分でしょうか？ どちらを希望されているのか質問文からは判断できませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

とりあえず、今回は標準入出力を操作する必要はなく、起動だけできればよかったので、ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteWで実現できました。
これで解決とさせていただきます。
ありがとうございました。